# Why i can't show new Ext.Window twice

Tags: javascript, extjs, window

I have a html with one div and two scripts with Ext Js 3.4.0

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/listaBancos.js"></script>
```

The file listaBancos.js show a Grid with toolbar button in the divListaBancos, the first time i click the button "Agregar" and i see the Window declared in altaBanco.js.

==============Part of the grid in listaBancos.js============

```
 tbar:[{
    text:'Agregar',
    tooltip:'Agrega un banco',
    iconCls:'add',
    handler: agregaBanco
}]

function agregaBanco(){
var win =Ext.getCmp('myWin');
win.show();
```

}

==============Window declared in altaBanco.js================

```
var winAltaBanco = new Ext.Window({
    id     : 'myWin',
    height : 250,
    width  : 400,

});
```

When i close the window then click the button again the windows doesn't showed.

Can you help me ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure in window  config close action is set to hide.

```
closeAction:'hide'
```

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tWHbV/)

Answer (score 1):

The default `close` action of a windows is `close`, i.e., it destroys the component, hence it cannot be accessed using `Ext.geCmp()` again since it doesn't exist on the `DOM` anymore. To achieve what you want either set `closeAction : hide` or

```
var cmp = Ext.getCmp('myId');
if(!cmp)
{
cmp = new Ext.Window({
  id : 'myId'
});
}
cmp.show();
```

Prefer hiding to recreating.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make any trick, simply remove your window id. In ExtJS component ids must be unique.